# update root state from feature state ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an app that displays blogs using ngrx

The main root state is as follows

```
import { Blog } from '../models/blog';

export interface AppState {
  readonly loaded: boolean;
  readonly blogs: {[key:number]:Blog}
}

export const initialState:AppState = {
  loaded: false,
   blogs: {}
}
```

I also have a feature module set up to administrate the blogs

```
StoreModule.forFeature('crudBlog', reducers)
```

What I'm wondering about now is; when I want to update, delete etc. a blog how do I get access to the AppState (root state) of my store from the feature reducer file

So I can do something like this;

```
function handleBlogUpdatedAction(state, action){
    const index = action.payload.index;
    const newState = Object.assign({}, rootState);
    newState[index] = action.payload.blog
return newState;
}
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

ngrx state is suppose to be immutable, you are changing the state with by assigning it `newState[index] = action.payload.blog`.

So for example, this is how your reducer could look like:

```
export function reducer(
  state = initialState,
  action
) : BlogState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATED_BLOG_SUCCESS: {
            const blog = action.payload;
            const entites = {
                ...state.entities,
                [blog.id]: blog
            };

            // below is how your new state is returned using the spread operator
            return {
                ...state,
                entities
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Where `initialState` is:

```
export interface BlogState {
    entities: { [id: number]: Blog };
    loaded: boolean;
    loading: boolean;
}

export const initialState : BlogState = {
  entities: {},
  loaded: false,
  loading: false,
};
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, the thing is I thought once I used "Object.assign" then that object can now be mutated, also the problem I have is that I need to get access to root state "AppState" from a feature state "CrudBlogState" is this possible?

Comment: I rarely had to do that, if i recall you would have to use `selector` to get the state from another feature state.

Comment: @Roy, maybe this will help you, https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/issues/159 See at bottom of the comment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look